# Why doesn't Aframe's dependencies attribute not working?

Tags: javascript, aframe, virtual-reality

I have the following simple example of initializing entities with components:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello, WebVR! - A-Frame</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Hello, WebVR! - A-Frame">
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.7.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <script>
    AFRAME.registerComponent('a', {
      dependencies: ['b']
    });
    // Initializes second.
    AFRAME.registerComponent('b', {
      dependencies: ['c']
    });
    // Initializes first.
    AFRAME.registerComponent('c', {});
  </script>
  <body>
    <a-scene>
    </a-scene>
  </body>
  <script>
    sceneEl = document.querySelector('a-scene');
    aEntity = document.createElement('a-entity');
    aEntity.setAttribute('a');
    sceneEl.appendChild(aEntity);
  </script>
</html>
```

This is from the documentation of Aframe regarding components and dependencies

> dependencies: allows for control on ordering of component initialization if a component depends on one or more other components. Component names specified in the dependencies array will be initialized left-to-right before initializing the current component. If the dependency have other dependency components, those other dependency components will be ordered in the same manner.

My question is why is this code not working. The code generates the `a-entity` as expected but no component is being attached. I would expect to see a, b, and c Attached to my entity. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like if you don't supply a value for setAttribute it's ignored.

Try `aEntity.setAttribute('a', '');` instead.

Console should show: `<a-entity c="" b="" a="" position="" rotation="" scale="" visible=""></a-entity>`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello, WebVR! - A-Frame</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Hello, WebVR! - A-Frame">
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.7.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <script>
    AFRAME.registerComponent('a', {
      dependencies: ['b']
    });
    // Initializes second.
    AFRAME.registerComponent('b', {
      dependencies: ['c']
    });
    // Initializes first.
    AFRAME.registerComponent('c', {});
  </script>
  <body>
    <a-scene>
    </a-scene>
  </body>
  <script>
    sceneEl = document.querySelector('a-scene');
    aEntity = document.createElement('a-entity');
    aEntity.setAttribute('a', '');
    sceneEl.appendChild(aEntity);
    console.log(aEntity)
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: I've also seen `.setAttribute('foo', true)` in use, but I haven't looked through the attribute parser to determine which, if either, would be more efficient.